# How to change lock screen image for the iPhone using swift

Tags: iphone, swift

I am making an app using Swift and plan to release it to the apple store. Is there any way to change the lock screen image automatically when you are not on the app by allowing certain permissions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sadly, there is no access to the lock screen image!